# ErrorMessageResourceName and ErrorMessage cannot both be set, but I'm only setting one

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

This is the error I'm getting using MVC2:

```
Either ErrorMessageString or ErrorMessageResourceName must be set, but not both.
```

It is coming from the [Required] Validation DataAnnotation.

Stack trace:

```
InvalidOperationException: Either ErrorMessageString or ErrorMessageResourceName must be set, but not both.]
   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.SetupResourceAccessor() +89338
   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.FormatErrorMessage(String name) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<Validate>d__1.MoveNext() +215
   System.Web.Mvc.<Validate>d__5.MoveNext() +735
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +424
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +732
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +475
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +152
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +709
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +162
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +453
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +371
```

I've boiled my view model down to this(it breaks any time there is a [Required] attribute, works fine without):

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[DisplayName("Property Name")]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

My controller returns an empty ViewModel, and the form in the view is completely blank...just a submit button.

Comment: check my answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36878989/6061777) on facing this error on custom validations.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem lies in setting the ErrorMessage to a blank string.  I would have to assume that at some point there is a check for String.Empty in the MVC code that is causing problems.

Setting the ErrorMessage to " "(one space) solved the issue.

Comment: That can be also set to null as well.

Answer (score 22):

In my case, I have write ErrorMessage = null, example :

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FORM_FIELD_VALIDATION_EMAIL", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(App_GlobalResources.Common.View_Common_Forms), ErrorMessage = null)]
```

`ErrorMessage = " "` don't work.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `[DataType(DataType.Text)]` has a validation message defined in resources (in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Resources) and the existence of that and your `[Required]` is causing this `InvalidOperationException`. Try Removing `[DataType]` or `[Required]` and see if the exception goes away.

Comment: Same result.  I'm going to revert the file to yesterday morning's and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simmilar issue with a custom ValidationAttribute.

In the IsValid method I was setting the ErrorMessage. The fix was to remove the assignation to the ErrorMessage propety...

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    //code before ...
    this.ErrorMessage = this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName); //NOT GOOD...
    ValidationResult validationResult = new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage, //And using the ErrorMessage Here...
        new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
    return validationResult;
}
```

I was writting Unit test and they were pasisng only if i was running/debugging one by one. But when I click "Run All", only the first one was passing? They are not Linked in any ways...

I also tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/20848920/4798459
Didn't work either.

So yeah, the fix was to remove the assignation to the ErrorMessage propety!