# Either ErrorMessageString or ErrorMessageResourceName must be set, but not both error using CreditCardAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my model:

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class CreditCard
    {
        [CreditCard(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "CardNumberInvalid")]
        public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my Messages.resx:

Name            Value

CardNumberInvalid   Check your card number is correct

And this is my view:

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.CreditCard
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CardNumber);
```

In MVC version 3 this works without error.  In MVC 4 when I go to this page I get an excpetion saying "Either ErrorMessageString or ErrorMessageResourceName must be set, but not both".  This is only happening with the CreditCardAttribute.  Other validation attributes such as RequiredAttribute work fine.  I have only set the ErrorMessageResourceName.  I have not set the ErrorMessageString, so do not understand what I have done wrong.  Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 154):

It's a known issue in .Net 4.5. Adding "ErrorMessage = null" named parameter should solve this.

Reference:
Reference link is broken now.
<s>http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/757298/emailaddress-attribute-is-unable-to-load-error-message-from-resource-mvc</s>

Comment: I got this same error while using the new `EmailAddress` data annotation. This successfully solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: But that would also remove any custom error messages set. Check Ians answer for a fool-proof way!
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16211476/268091

Comment: @MEMark this was in response to a need to set error message directly from resource. Not sure I understand reference to a custom error message.

Comment: @DipenBhikadya, I'm just pointing out that this answer would also remove any custom messages set on the attribute. At least for me that is very common, translating the standard message in a resource file, and sometimes providing a specialized messag on the attribute itself. For anyone coming to this question with that need (which is what I did myself) my link will prove useful.

Comment: I had this exception with named parameeter `ErrorMessage = ""`. Even `ErrorMessage = null` didn't help, but removing the parameeter at all helped.

Comment: It's the same for the `UrlAttribute` data annotation.

Comment: @DipenBhikadya the link is broken

Comment: @HakamFostok - it's almost 4 years old answer, please update it with correct link if you have it.

Answer (score 17):

```
[CreditCard(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "CardNumberInvalid", ErrorMessage = null)]
```

Adding the `ErrorMessage = null` will fix your problem.

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem because I had implemented a `RequiredAttributeAdapter`, which was setting the `ErrorMessageResourceName` property automatically.

You can fix it by checking to see if the ErrorMessage property has been set before setting the `ErrorMessageResourceName`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a new instance of the RequiredAttributeAdapter, used for switching the default required message
/// format
/// </summary>
public CustomMessageRequiredAttributeAdapter(
    ModelMetadata metadata,
    ControllerContext context,
    RequiredAttribute attribute
)
    : base(metadata, context, attribute)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.ErrorMessage))
    {
        attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (ValidationMessages);
        attribute.ErrorMessageResourceName = "PropertyValueRequired";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! I had been fooling around a long time with the attribute properties without succeeding.

Answer (score 1):

Since anyone who is using custom validation attributes and also wants to load error messages from resources for localization purposes, would face this problem i share my workaround here.
assume that you have a custom validation attribute like this one

```
[FileTypeMustBe("jpg")]
public HttpPostedFileBase MyFile {get; set;}
```

in your custom validation attribute add this code

```
public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
          ErrorMessageString, name, ValidFileType);
    }
```

ValidFileType is name of a property which takes the input argument of custom validation attribute (jpg here),well now we can decorate our model property the way we like it to be

```
[FileTypeMustBe("jpg", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "WrongFileTypeError")]
public HttpPostedFileBase MyFile {get; set;}
```

as you see there's no need to add `ErrorMessage=null` anymore cause we took care of it in custom validation class. just do not forget if you had initialized any error message string in your custom validation , you have to remove it now and use `FormatErrorMessage` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simmilar issue with a custom ValidationAttribute.

In the IsValid method I was setting the ErrorMessage. The fix was to remove the assignation to the ErrorMessage propety...

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    //code before ...
    this.ErrorMessage = this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName); //NOT GOOD...
    ValidationResult validationResult = new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage, //And using the ErrorMessage Here...
        new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
    return validationResult;
}
```

I was writting Unit test and they were pasisng only if i was running/debugging one by one. But when I click "Run All", only the first one was passing? They are not Linked in any ways...

So yeah, just remove the remove the assignation to the ErrorMessage propety

I hope it will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `ErrorMessage`  as `""` in .Net Core 3.1 API.

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("^[1-9]\\d*$", ErrorMessage ="")]
public int fieldName { get; set; }
```

I change to `ErrorMessage ="Invalid Value Or some other message"` and the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
```

with

```
[Required()]
```

worked for me, there is no meaning of keeping **ErrorMessage** with a blank string either

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when using a custom 'ValidationAttribute' that returned a `ValidationResult` instead of a `bool`. When I returned an unassigned string with the `ValidationResult` it would throw the error

`Either ErrorMessageString or ErrorMessageResourceName must be set, but not both`

When I returned `ValidationResult(null)` the field would never validate, it was always invalid. Looks like .NET looks for a `ValidationResult` to determine if the field is valid and not if it contains an error string. In order to get it to validate and get rid of the error I needed to return a `null` result.

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    string errMsg = null;

    // Do validation and assign the error message

    return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errMsg)) ? new ValidationResult(errMsg) : null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem on a property that I was localizing. I had defined the ErrorMessageResourceType and then the ErrorMessageResourceName but by mistake put the ErrorMessage atrtribute on as well which threw the exception

```
[NotEqualTo("User_Name", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(LROResources.Global), ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserPasswordCannotBeUsername", ErrorMessage = "The password cannot be the same as your Username.")]
```

So in my case by just removing `ErrorMessage` I fixed the problem.

Comment: This is pretty obvious when you look at the error. The OP didn't had the `ErrorMessage` set however, so it shouldn't have given the error. The reason that it did is a bug in the Data Annotation Attributes itself, as mentioned by [@DipenBhikadya](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12488268/1682559). Your problem does indeed fix YOUR problem when you remove the `ErrorMessage`, which was pretty clear from the error given, but it's a different problem (with the same error message) as OP's.